# Polymorphic model in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, polymorphism

Concept of polymorphic model. For example we have this table comment:

```
+----+---------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
| id | commentable_id| commentable_type  |            comments_text           |
+----+---------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 |    2          |      youtube      |        youtube rocks, buddy!       |
|  2 |    6          |       vimeo       |        hey, vimeo is better!       |
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
```

- Where youtube and vimeo refer to the model `class Youtube(){…}` and `class Vimeo(){…}`
  youtube can has many comments, and vimeo can has many comments, and comment belong to youtube and vimeo.
- If we want to add another model that has many comments in the future we just need to add that in `commentable_type` without adding more field like `something_id` into comment table.
- If we want to add dailymotion, we just need to add dailymotion in `commentable_type` without adding field `dailymotion_id` into comment table
- `commentable_id = 2` refer to `youtube_id = 2` in youtube table, and `commentable_id` = 6 refer to `vimeo_id` = 6 in vimeo table.

In Laravel (PHP) we can simply do like this:

```
class Youtube extends Eloquent{

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}

class Vimeo extends Eloquent{

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}

class Comment extends Eloquent{

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

and we can simply access them like this:

```
$youtube = Youtube::find(1);
$youtube->comments;

$vimeo = Vimeo::find(1);
$vimo->comments;
```

My Questions are, how to derive the relationship of this ORM in ASP MVC? And how we can easily access them to do CRUD operation?

Comment: This is an ORM question, not an ASP.NET question.. which ORM are you using as each ORM will have different ways to solve this problem?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Maybe my question about ORM is wrong. How to this in ASP MVC? how to define this relationship in ASP MVC? So we can easily access those comments

Comment: What code do you currently have? I don't know what ORM you're using to access your model(s) so I can't possibly tell you how to access it..

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff I'm using EF code first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is entirely what you're looking for, but something like this should suffice:

```
public abstract class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Youtube : Video
{
    /* Other properties */
}

public class Vimeo : Video
{
    /* Other properties */
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    public int VideoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Video Video { get; set; }
}

public class VideoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Youtube> Youtubes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vimeo> Vimeos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

This creates the following structure when querying:

[image]

To access it you would have to do something like this:

```
var context = new VideoContext();

var vimeos = context.Vimeos.Include(x => x.Comments).ToList();
var youtubes = context.Youtubes.Include(x => x.Comments).ToList();
```

Comment: how do we access them later? is like this possible Youtube.comments , Vimeo.comments ?

Comment: See my edit.. take a look at this for some basic information with working with EF and MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: TQ.. this link kinda helpful as well, have been 1 year didn't touch asp http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inheritance http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
public class Video {
// Id etc.
public virtual IList<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}

public class Youtube : Video{
// Id etc.
}

public class Vimeo : Video{
// Id etc.
}

public class Comment {
// comment props
 public virtual IList<Video> Videos {get; set;}
}
```